# Optimize 2D array code in Pascal

Tags: arrays, optimization, pascal, multidimensional-array

I have a code that generates 2D array that looks like this

```
0      0      0      0      0     34     41     43     45      0
0      0      0      0     25     30     35     42     44      0
0      0      0     14     20     26     31     36     40      0
0      0      1      8     15     21     27     32     37      0
0      0      0      2      9     16     22     28     33      0
0      0      0      0      3     10     17     23     29      0
0      0      0      0      0      4     11     18     24      0
0      0      0      0      0      0      5     12     19      0
0      0      0      0      0      0      0      6     13      0
0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      7      0
```

And the source code part for generating numbers is

```
   j:=3;
   for i:=4 to 10 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=4;
   for i:=4 to 9 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
    j:=4;
   for i:=3 to 8 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=5;
   for i:=3 to 7 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=5;
   for i:=2 to 6 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=6;
   for i:=2 to 5 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
      j:=6;
   for i:=1 to 4 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
     j:=7;
   for i:=1 to 3 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=7;
   for i:=1 to 2 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
   j:=8;
   for i:=1 to 2 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
    j:=9;
   for i:=1 to 1 do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
```

I need the code to be optimized and make it small as possible and do the same function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Things like this tend to be very compiler-specific. If performance is really important here you may want to try and manually unroll your loops.

Comment: I want it to be optimized and still have cycles but fewer.

Answer (score 0):

From your statement "I need the code to be optimized and make it small as possible" I assume your are optimizing for code length.
Sorry if I have missed something, but you could define a function like

```
f(j,k,l)
begin
   for i:=k to l do
   begin
      ms[i,j]:=wrk;
        wrk:=wrk+1;
         j:=j+1
   end;
end;
```

It would make your code much smaller, you would call the function like this.

```
f(3,4,10);
f(4,4,9);
f(4,3,8);
...
```

Please add the details, I haven't used Pascal for a while.
Please note that it won't make your code more efficient, the program will run a little bit slower because of the function calls.

Comment: Okay. Here is the thing. I have much larger code that has a cycle inside a cycle that generates 0 and my part [here](http://pastebin.com/4niyr3Rv) And i only needed to make one part inside that code that generates a pattern like that. I thought it may has too much cycles. So i want it to be still a cycle but to generate numbers in that pattern. Hope this helps. If you need more info i will tell. I dont need efficiency but lesser code.

Comment: I think  following my suggestion from above is a good start.  You will then get rid of the
   "for i:=4 to 10 do ..."
blocks.
The double for loop before is the initialization, the double for loop after is output.

Comment: I just optimized my self [here](http://pastebin.com/90Dza2uu).The probelem was i didn't understand the way the numbers ar put in inside the 2D array, but i know the corret way. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your optimized program is doing the same as the old version?

Comment: It does it differently because the way to fill the array i found out must look like this given last code. The first way that i put was very wrong. I didn't red the instructions correctly. Now its correct. I am very sure.